# Create a Column and populate based on existing data SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, crystal-reports

I'm migrating a report from Crystal where i was able to create a column and fill using this formula...

```
if ({@SD Profile}="null") and ({@HD Profile 2}="null")
then ""
else
    if ({@HD Profile 2}="null")
    then "SD only"
    else
        if ({@SD Profile}="null")
        then "HD only"
        else 
            if({@SD Companion}="1")
            then "HD+SD"
            else "HD/SD"
```

I'd like to accomplish the same thing using SQL where i populate the values of a column based on the data in 3 other columns. Note I'm not adding a column to the DB just inserting into the report.

I've created the empty column in my SELECT statement using

```
CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(30)) as "Content Type",
"SD_format"."name" as "SD Format",
"HD_format"."name" as "HD Format",
"destination"."sd_companion_required_flag"
```

Basically something like... If SD_Format.name ='null' then Content_Type = '' etc.

Comment: Can you please share table structure with some sample data,So that we can understand your problem?

Comment: well I'm joining multiple tables, and my query is too long to cut and paste into a comment. I'm more curious if there is a good way to say, "IF column a contains a blank cell, populate column c with x" IF column A contains anything and column B contains nothing, populate column c with Y"

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to replace the 'if' statement by a 'case' statement:

```
select
  case
    when SD_Profile is null and HD_Profile is null then ''
    when HD_Profile is null then 'SD only'
    when SD_Profile is null then 'HD only'
    when Destination = '1' then 'HD + SD'
    else 'HD/SD'
  end as 'Content_Type'
from ...
```

Comment: Thanks  - I'm going to try this now and let you know how it works.

Comment: That worked like a charm, Thanks HashPsi - appreciate the quick response and solid anser.

Answer (score 0):

```
*"SD_format"."name" as "SD Format",
 "HD_format"."name" as "HD Format",
    case
   when "SD_format"."name" is null and "HD_format"."name" is null then ''
   when "HD_format"."name" is null then 'SD only'
   when "SD_format"."name" is null then 'HD only'
   when "destination"."sd_companion_required_flag" = '1' then 'HD + SD'
   else 'HD/SD'
  end as "Content_Type",
```